# Bootstrap datepicker with Encore and Symfony4

Tags: jquery, webpack, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker, webpack-encore

I think this is a easy one.

I have a Symfony 4 application, with Webpack/Encore.

I have installed bootstrap 4 and everything works fine; I am trying to install bootstrap-datepicker.

So, I have created a file called `datepicker.js`, here is the content:

```
// js
require('bootstrap-datepicker');
require('../../../node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.it.min');

// css
require('../../../node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css');

'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({

    });
});
```

JQuery and Bootstrap is provided by another file, called `vendors.js`:

```
// js
require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');

// scss
require('../scss/vendors.scss');
```

`vendors.js` is a shared entry. Here is the portion of my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
Encore
    ...

    // shared entries
    .createSharedEntry('vendors', [
        './assets/js/vendors.js'
    ])

    ...
```

On the page on I want to use datepicker I have the classic error:

```
jquery.js:3869 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
```

Why am I wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same problem and discovered what may be wrong with `bootstrap-datepicker`.

In my case, I discovered that the jQuery instance used by the library is the one which is required in its `package.json` file. So it was never imported in my project jQuery instance therefore I had the `TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function` when trying to create a datepicker.

I found further information in this [bootstrap-datepicker issue](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/2221#issuecomment-335122428) which points that in the `1.7.0` version, the `jQuery` dependency was marked as `peerDependency`. In others versions, it is a `dependency` and apparently this instance is used for the library instead of the project's one.

I tried to add this version in my project:

```sh
yarn add bootstrap-datepicker@1.7.0
```

After that, it works like a charm. But I can't get stuck with older version.

---

Fortunately, I found a topic about [avoiding multiple versions of jQuery](https://makandracards.com/makandra/69621-webpack-how-to-avoid-multiple-versions-of-jquery) and the solution is to force the version of a dependency for a specific package:

```
{
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "1.8.0",
    "jquery": "2.2.4",
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "bootstrap-datepicker/jquery": "2.2.4"
  }
}
```

With this config, bootstrap-datepicker uses the same jQuery instance as the rest of my project and I can create my datepickers as expected.

Comment: Haaaa. Thank you so much, I was desperate. Your solution worked for me !

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you already solved the problem.
Assuming your filesystem is organized like that (like in my case):

```
Root/
  assets/
    css/
      app.scss
    js/
      app.js
```

Here is what I did:

First of all I have installed the bootstrap datepicker:

```
npm i bootstrap-datepicker-webpack
```

This package is the one suggested but in my case it brought some issues, so I did like Edhrendal did:

```
yarn add bootstrap-datepicker@1.7.0
```

I checked the libraries in node_modules folder and I had both bootstrap-datepicker and bootstrap-datepicker-webpack.

At this stage, for styles, I edited app.scss by adding;

```
@import "~bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3";
```

and app.js

```
require("bootstrap-datepicker");
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

Note: require("bootstrap-datepicker-webpack") didn't work.

Then I ran:

```
yarn run encore dev
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Jquery-ui , its a dependency i will show you an example.

```
require('webpack-jquery-ui/datepicker');
require("bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js");
require("bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css");

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#datepicker").each(function () {
        $(this).datepicker({});
      });
    });
```

it worked for me, hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in the code sample you gave that you're not including the "**datepicker.js**" you've created: in your "**vendor.js**", you should **require("./whatever-path/datepicker.js");** as for Bootstrap & jQuery.